# Why does MySQL Query skips null value? How to prevent MySQL skipping the NULL value?

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to know why MySQL Query serves different number of columns when some values in NULL or Zero(Integer Case).

> For example, I have due as "0" integer (not sting - without Quotes) in some columns. When I make a query, I want to show "0" integer. But that column is skipped.

Can't it return just nothing instead of skipping the NULL value?
How Can we overcome this error?

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `2014-02-20`";
  $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    while ($this_item = current($row)) {
      echo key($row)."-->".$row[key($row)]."<br />";
      next($row);
    }
    echo "<br />";
  }


?>
```

I see different results like: 
Case 1 (with 0 in due column)

```
qty-->1
amount-->390
```

Case 2 (with some value in due)

```
activity-->sales
qty-->1
amount-->25500
```

Comment: where did you get that idea of using while current?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `foreach` in the inner loop:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    foreach($row as $key => $value) {
        echo "$key --> $value <br />";
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
```

A `foreach` loop will iterate through the whole `$row` array regardless of values that might evaluate to false.

Comment: Tell him about the "why" part too :)

Comment: Thank you very much as I has wiped my sneezy nose. Thank you again. But if you could tell me the reason why it happens, it would be incredible

Comment: it's simply because a while loop will run unless the condition evaluates to `true`. `current()` will return the current *value* of the array, if this evaluates to `false` the loop will stop. That's it. `while` was just the improper kind of loop here.